# Running through different parts of the input

Tags: c++

I don't really know how to explain this so I'll just give an example and do my best at explaining.
For example I get this as input from the client:

"TREGPRABCNPRX" (Without pressing enter)

Now I want to take the first 3 letters and put them into different chars (a1, a2, a3 : 'T' , 'R' , 'E').
Then after I'm done with them I'll move to the following 3 and save their value into (a1, a2, a3 with the values : 'G', 'P', 'R'), it will do so until it encounters a 'X' at the end .
The trick is that you can't use strings / arrays.

I hope the explanation was good enough for you to understand.

Comment: Can you use C++? Streams? Why can't you use arrays?

Comment: Well it's for a bigger project. I've been told that I'm not allowed to use strings/arrays. And of course I need to use streams.

Comment: @user1885604 That seems rather arbitrary, you can use streams but not strings? Did you get a reason?

Comment: You actually don't really *have to* use streams - you can use C calls that would do this without. It arguably wouldn't be C++ code anymore, but thats why I asked. Streams use lots of dynamically allocated memory, so if you can't use strings and arrays, my guess would be that streams are out of question as well. So its not that much "of course" :)

Comment: @Borgleader Because the real input stream could be immensely longer than the short sample given, or just because it's a waste to store all input when you're only interested in a character triplet at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like

```
std::stringstream s("TREGPRABCNPRX");
char c;
while (s >> c && c != 'X')
{
    char a1 = c;
    char a2 = 0;
    char a3 = 0;
    if (s >> a2 >> a3)
        process(a1, a2, a3);
}
```

then that's how I would do it.